# Deserializing 'object' (anyType) within an XML document to a specific object type

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have some legacy code that used ArrayList's to serialize data out, this yields xml types of `<anyType xsi:type="SomeType">`. They all share the same data type so is pointless and yields code that is a mess.

Is there any elegant way of coercing this type of data in to a List when deserializing, short of pre-sanitizing the xml before it's deserialized?

Basically, I want to turn code from

```
[Serializable()]
public class SomeContainer
{
    public ArrayList SomeDataList1
    public ArrayList SomeDataList2
    public ArrayList SomeDataList3
    public ArrayList SomeDataList4
}
```

to

```
[Serializable()]
public class SomeContainer
{
    public List<SomeType1> SomeDataList1
    public List<SomeType2> SomeDataList2
    public List<SomeType3> SomeDataList3
    public List<SomeType4> SomeDataList4
}
```

So I'm interested in the ArrayList -> List translation, rather than the container.

Comment: Lookup `[XmlInclude]`. It may help. You can also try playing with `[XmlArray]` and `[XmlArrayItem]`. Generally, some combination of those attributes in your schema gets things working. At one point, I remembered all this, now I mostly use trial and error

Comment: it sounds like you're using `XmlSerializer` - if so: note that it doesn't check (or care about) `[Serializable]` - that's for something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark your classes with the right XML attributes, you can get your `SomeContainer` class to mimic the behavior of `ArrayList` for deserializing XML.

You may not care, but you would need to have your class implement `IEnumerable` if you also want your class to be *serialized* the same as with ArrayList.

See the example below for full serialize/deserialize that looks the same as ArrayList.  If you want, you can remove the `IEnumerable` implementation, and you will see that the serialization changes.  Deserializing with "anyType" still works without implementing `IEnumerable`, though.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    [XmlType(nameof(SomeContainer))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(SomeType))]
    public class SomeContainer : IEnumerable
    {
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(SomeType))]
        public List<SomeType> SomeDataList = new List<SomeType>();

        public void Add(object o)
        {
            SomeDataList.Add(o as SomeType);
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return SomeDataList.Count;
        }
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return SomeDataList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class SomeType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "SomeName";
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            SomeContainer s1 = new SomeContainer();
            s1.SomeDataList.Add(new SomeType());
            string tempPath = "c:\\temp\\test.xml";
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeContainer));

            // serialize
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempPath))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, s1);

            }

            /* Produces the following XML:
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <SomeContainer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                  <anyType xsi:type="SomeType">
                    <Name>SomeName</Name>
                  </anyType>
                </SomeContainer>
            */

            // deserialize
            SomeContainer s2;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(tempPath))
            {
                s2 = (SomeContainer)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
            }

            // check contents of s2 as you please
        }
    }
}
```

(@Flydog57's comment was right, and came literally as I was typing this.)

Comment: I've accepted this answer for an explicit solution to how the original question was perceived, I've however updated the original question to be more explicit.  I tried your solution to do a "AnyList<T>" to replace "List<T>" using the same principles, as this allows for multiple List<T>'s in once container.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the comment I left for the answer by Sean Skelly.

```
    public class AnyList<T> : IEnumerable where T : class
    {
        List<T> holder = new List<T>();

        public int Count()
        {
            return holder.Count;
        }

        public void Add(object objectToAdd)
        {
            T typedObjectToAdd = objectToAdd as T;
            if (typedObjectToAdd != null)
            {
                holder.Add(typedObjectToAdd);
            }
            // If you can't guarantee the input data, should perhaps inform some data will be skipped.
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return holder.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

And XmlInclude is important, as it might deduce by itself, or might not and just pass through an XmlNode instead, which may or may not be useful for custom transforms.

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeType1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeType2))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeType3))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeType4))]
public class SomeContainer
{
    public AnyList<SomeType1> SomeDataList1
    public AnyList<SomeType2> SomeDataList2
    public AnyList<SomeType3> SomeDataList3
    public AnyList<SomeType4> SomeDataList4
}
```

This is clean enough meaning I can change back to List once the data has normalized.

Would have been better if C# had generic attributes.